# rest api get return HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

i have this entity class to store movie details.

```
@Table(name = "movie")
public class Movie {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String title;
    private String category;
    private double rating;
}
```

Now i also have a rest api to get by movie id
How do i modify my rest api to return http error code 204, to show no content has been found.

```
@GetMapping("/movie/{id}")
public Movie getMovieById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Integer id) {
    if (service.get(id)!=null) {
        return service.get(id);
    } else {
        return HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

204 No Content is not the appropriate status code here; that means "the resource exists/existed but I am not sending contents". This is specifically the case for 404 Not Found. You can either throw an exception (such as `ResponseStatusException`) or change your controller to return `ResponseEntity<Movie>`.

Answer (score 0):

In case asked for content is not available you could stick to 404 Resource Not found. Using some other obscure (not 204) HTTP status code is not a good idea as it can cause browser to react differently.
In your case, returning any empty response body, is also fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can do something like below,

@Table(name = "movie")
public class Movie {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String title;
    private String category;
    private double rating;
    public String status;
}

@GetMapping("/movie/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Movie> getMovieById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Integer id) {

ResponseEntity<Movie> response = null;

    if (service.get(id)!=null) {
        Movie movie =  service.get(id);
        ResponseEntity.ok(movie)
    } else {
        Movie movie = new Movie()
        movie.setStatus("FAILURE");
        ResponseEntity response = new ResponseEntity<>(movie, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    }
    
    return response
}
```